Cart Counter bubble no hover colour in Menu Cart
Have a issue that I have been trying to solve for a few days now. I am building a wordpress website using Elementor and the Astra theme. I have added a Menu Cart to the top of my website and when hoovering over the basket/ total/ item counter the basket and total will change to the hover colour black but their is no option to use a hover colour for the item counter, dose anyone have any suggestions or code that may help with this?
Link to site I am currently working on: https://theproducersgreenroom.com/
I am new to website building, this is actually only my second in a few weeks, both sites for myself and I know pretty much nothing about coding myself, I have attempted to open the inspector on my computer and can get the item counter to change to black when hovered on their but the code I alter on their dose not work when copied to my sites custom CSS
I have tried altering code on inspector  of my iMAc which I can get to work but this code will not work when inputed into custom CSS
